# python convert sorted Double linked list to BST

Tags: python, binary-search-tree, doubly-linked-list

The idea is quite similar to most of others, do a inorder in place traversal treat left as prevNode and right as nextNode
for Some reason it just cannot work.. seems not running recursion?

I tested my DoubleLinked list is contructed correctly by printing preNode and nextNode

but is still say 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'val'
The problem is on buildTree

Any one plz help

```
class LinkNode(object):
    def __init__(self, val):
        self.val = val
        self.nextNode = None
        self.prevNode = None


def buildLinkList(arr):
    dummy = head = LinkNode(None)
    dummy.nextNode = head
    for val in arr:
        new_node = LinkNode(val)
        new_node.prevNode = head
        head.nextNode = new_node
        head = head.nextNode
    return dummy.nextNode

def printLink(head):
    while head:
        print head.val
        if not head.nextNode: 
            #print head.val
            return head
        head = head.nextNode

def buildTree(head, n):
    if n <= 0:
        return None
    left = buildTree(head, n / 2)
    print head.val
    root = head
    root.prevNode = left
    head = head.nextNode
    root.nextNode = buildTree(head, n - n / 2 - 1)
    return root


def inorder(root):
    if root:
        inorder(root.prevNode)
        print root.val
        inorder(root.nextNode) 

arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
head = buildLinkList(arr)
#print head.val
root = buildTree(head, 7)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
def recursiveMakeDLL(node, prevNode=None):
    if node is None:
        return None

    left = recursiveMakeDLL(node.left, prevNode)
    node.left = left if left is not None else prevNode
    if left is not None:
        left.right = node
    elif prevNode is not None:
        prevNode.right = node

    prevToReturn = recursiveMakeDLL(node.right, node)
    return prevToReturn if prevToReturn is not None else node


def makeDLL(root):
    root = recursiveMakeDLL(root)
    head = root
    tail = root
    while head.left is not None:
        head = head.left
    while tail.right is not None:
        tail = tail.right
    head.left = tail
    tail.right = head

    return head
```

The idea is to pass the prevNode as part of the recursion so that we can set the left of current not to it when the stack pops back up from the in-order traversal.

Answer (score 0):

head is not updated in every recursion call,so here head should be global variable (like how double pointer is used in C).

update your buildTree function like

```
def buildTree(n):
    global head
    if n<=0 :
        return None
    left = buildTree(n/2)
    root = head
    root.prevNode = left
    head = head.nextNode
    root.nextNode = buildTree(n-n/2-1)
    return root
```